# Azure EventGrid Validation Failing Using OkObjectResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-eventgrid

I am attempting synchronous handshake validation for EventGrid using the example from Microsoft found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/receive-events)

```
public IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post")] HttpRequestData OriginalRequest)
{
    Log.LogInformation("HTTP Request Received");
    BinaryData RawEvents = BinaryData.FromStream(OriginalRequest.Body);
    EventGridEvent[] EventGridEvents = EventGridEvent.ParseMany(RawEvents);

    foreach (EventGridEvent Event in EventGridEvents) {
        if (Event.TryGetSystemEventData(out object EventData)) {
            if (EventData is SubscriptionValidationEventData ValidationEventData) {

                var ResponseData = new {
                    ValidationResponse = ValidationEventData.ValidationCode
                };
                Log.LogInformation("Validation Complete");
                return new OkObjectResult(ResponseData);
            }
            else {
                RelayEvent(OriginalRequest);
            }
        }
    }
    return new OkObjectResult(string.Empty);
```

This is the result I should be getting:

```
{
  "ValidationResponse": "512d38b6-c7b8-40c8-89fe-f46f9e9622b6"
}
```

But, this is the result that I am getting:

```
{
  "Value": {
    "ValidationResponse": "512d38b6-c7b8-40c8-89fe-f46f9e9622b6"
  },
  "Formatters": [],
  "ContentTypes": [],
  "DeclaredType": null,
  "StatusCode": 200
}
```

I recognize that this is just the `OkObjectResult` serialized, but that doesn't seem to track with what the Microsoft example claims I should be getting. I don't think I missed anything, and I even tried making my code async to match the example, but that didn't change anything, of course.

How do I get the result that Microsoft is getting, and why is there a discrepancy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a misunderstanding on my part. The example in the Microsoft docs is for a full blown MVC application and `OkObjectResult` is an MVC class. Azure Functions is not an MVC application, so the correct design was to return `HttpResponseData`